# FireDac: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'declare'

Tags: sql-server, firedac

I want to run the following query:

```
Qry.SQL.Text := 'declare @test bit; set @test = 1; select @test;';
Qry.Open;
```

This causes the error "**Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'declare'**", but the Query shows the expected "1". 
If I run that sql in the Microsoft Management-Studio everything works fine.
So why I get the error and how to solve it? Anyone an idea?

Regards
Maggi

Comment: Use profiler to see what command firedac is actually sending to SQL Server when you execute this.

Comment: Did you specify any non-default options for Qry ?

Comment: I found the problem: We are using `RecordCountMode := cmTotal` and thats forces FireDac to execute a Query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (declare @test bit; set @test = 1; select @test;) A`